# llvm-c/Types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a toy compiler for a subset of C. I'm using flex, bison, and LLVM for ASTs. For generating ASTs, I have written a header file that includes definitions of nodes and inheritance details. The header is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <llvm-6.0/llvm/IR/Value.h>

....
```

After compiling my files using the following sequence of commands:

```
bison -d parser.y -o parser.cpp
flex -o tokens.cpp tokens.l
g++ -o parser parser.cpp tokens.cpp main.cpp
```

Then compiler throws the following errors:

```
In file included from node.h:3:0,
                 from parser.y:2:
/usr/include/llvm-6.0/llvm/IR/Value.h:17:10: fatal error: llvm-c/Types.h: No such file or directory
 #include "llvm-c/Types.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from node.h:3:0,
                 from tokens.l:3:
/usr/include/llvm-6.0/llvm/IR/Value.h:17:10: fatal error: llvm-c/Types.h: No such file or directory
 #include "llvm-c/Types.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from node.h:3:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/llvm-6.0/llvm/IR/Value.h:17:10: fatal error: llvm-c/Types.h: No such file or directory
 #include "llvm-c/Types.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried searching the "include" directory, and the "Types.h" file is somewhere else and not in the "llvm/IR" directory. Should include any path during compilation? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I see you\re using the llvm-c API even though you're using C++ files. That sounds odd. You might be able to do it, but you'll be unique. Most C++ users use the native C++ API, not the C wrapper. You might consider eliminating instead of solving this problem by switching to the C++ API.

Comment: I'm using C++ API. The error is in the library file "llvm-6.0/llvm/IR/Value.h", which uses "llvm-c/Types.h"

Comment: Have you installed LLVM or built from source?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old but I just run into the same problem and couldn't find an answer so I had to figure out. Adding the solution here might help others.

The same way you had to add the prefix "llvm-6.0" to include Value.h, you'd have to do the same for llvm-c. It is not advisable to edit system include files, so I did it in the g++ call (I'm using llvm 10, but should be the same for other versions):

```
g++ -I/usr/include/llvm-10 -I/usr/include/llvm-c-10 -o parser parser.cpp tokens.cpp main.cpp
```